# How to list keys without serial number in REDIS?

Tags: redis, nosql

I am trying to list keys with specific pattern like below:

```
KEYS "*Team*"
```

and I am getting resultset with serial number like below:

> 1) "TeamMetricSummary_google_bps_app_google wfep
>   league_chambersc2016:04-03-2016_06-04-2016"
>
> 2) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00TTeamMetricSummary_google_bps_app_google wfep
>   league_malini.gto:12-06-2015_04-02-2016"

My problem is that I want to avoid serial number in result set.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. Redis will return the whole key. You can use regex  or string operations like split in your application logic to achieve this. For this you must know your input. For example if your key is in a pattern like `xTeamNamey`. where x and y are some constraints (serial number) you want to avoid, you can insert your key like `x:TeamName:y`. In retrieval you can use `string.split(":")[1]` to get the TeamName.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your specific question**:
Redis supports Lua scripting. If you're on a version of Redis that is bundled with Lua version 5.0 or above, you Lua script can use [regular expressions](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html). Write a Lua script that does `redis.call` of `KEYS` command and then does pattern matching to remove serial numbers for you.

**Alternative**:
By the way, assuming above is part of software that runs in production, here is what I would suggest: Don't use `KEYS` command on production! As [it's documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys) says, Redis has to go through **all the keys** to get keys matching your pattern. Alternatively, you may consider doing *shadow writes* to a Redis `set` that's trimmed of serial number every time you add a key. When you need list of keys, you can read the whole set. However, you'll have to manually handle the expiration of keys.

Comment: Another alternative to `KEYS` is using `SCAN`. In v3.2 and above it can also be used from a Lua script.